# Redirect from english version of one domain to new domain at wix

Tags: redirect, velo

How to add redirect from "old/en"  to "new" domain on the platform "wix"? Help please

Comment: Maybe this resource is helpfull for you [https://support.wix.com/en/article/setting-up-301-redirects-from-one-url-to-another](https://support.wix.com/en/article/setting-up-301-redirects-from-one-url-to-another)

Comment: I studied the documentation, it’s not indicated there

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more, do you want to redirect from `example.org/old/en` to `example.org/new` or from `example.org/old/en` to `newdomain.tld`?

Comment: The second option